# Z-index issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, slideshow, overlap

I have "Awkward Showcase" running in my page, but above I have a dropdown menu. The thing is that the showcase overlaps the menu and it is not completely visible.

I could correct that changing z-index, but it only works when I put:

**negative Index to Awkward Showcase**

**positive index to DropDown Menu**

Because of this, as the showcase has arrows to navigate trough sliders, there is no way to click on each. It seems like they (arrows) arre behind a transparent layer, because they arre visible, but inactive.

My codes:

### Menu

```
    <div id="navmenucontainer">
<ul id="navmenu">
    <li class="main" onclick="javascript: Mostrar(this);" id="menitem1"><a href="#" class="item">Productores</a>
        <div class="sub" onmouseout="setTimeout('Cierro(this)', 1000);" onmouseover="Sigue(this);" style="width:204px; overflow:hidden;">
         Some menu items
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

### Slideshow

```
<div id="showcase" class="showcase">
                            <div class="showcase-slide">
                                <div class="showcase-content">
                                    <div class="showcase-content-wrapper">
                                       <img src="images/1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="showcase-caption">

                                </div>
                             </div>
```

### CSS

```
#navmenucontainer {
    z-index:999999;
}

*/ul#navmenu div.sub{
    display: none;
    background: url('images/menu/bgcat.png') repeat-x bottom #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top:26;
    left:0;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    width:1240px;
    /*border-right:1px solid silver;*/
    border:1px solid silver;
    z-index:99999;
    zoom:1;
}

ul#navmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  /*border: 0 none;*/
  padding: 0;
  float:left; /*For Gecko*/
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  height: 20px;
}

ul#navmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

.showcase
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The overlapping occurs with ".sub" div, and ".showcase".

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot, but since it is IE after all... It could be either (almost)correct or disaster.. I have encountered the same problem, and it is a different solution every time depending on ones luck.. (IE sucks, just to quote and agree on the earlier comments)

Add this to your html

```
     <!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">

#navmenucontainer {
      z-index:3000;
}

ul#navmenu {
      z-index:2000;
}

ul#navmenu div.sub {
      z-index:1000;
}

.showcase {
      position: relative;
      z-index:0;
      margin: 0;
}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
```

Inspired from http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: With this solution, slider is overlapping menu in IE 7

Comment: I am making an image of what I am getting

Comment: Try and replace the position in ´ */ul#navmenu div.sub{´ with relative, and as well add position relative to the other navmenu elements (ul.and li) add z index to them too. This is the most common fix on this well known bug. "Adding a ´position:relative´ to the part that is dropping down." this is because it has to be a value that is relative to its parent.. IE doesnt understand what to do elsewise. Z index 1000 = 0, unless position is relative.. Then zindex 1000 = 1000 more than the parent's.

Comment: It did not work. I do not know what to do, I am stucked since last month. Too much.